# Как сделать на python ежесекундный web-scrapping публичных данных, обновляемых на целевой странице с помощью js?

Tags: django

Всем здравствуйте!

Как можно это сделать без перспективы залететь в бан? Парсить нужно в течение суток, недель, месяцев.

Целевой сайт - достаточно серьезный, поэтому, я думаю, что использование `VPN` там не прокатит.

Сначала рассматривал вариант в `tor` прописать дополнительно 4 порта и он будет подставлять разные `ip` при каждом заходе на сайт. Но я думаю, что при ежесекундном скраппинге - 4 порта - это очень мало. Кроме того, нашел отзывы, что `ip` `tor` бывают забанены, да и работает он медленновато.

Использовать задержки в несколько сеунд с различным интервалом - не вариант. Данные нужно именно получать в режиме реального времени.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, у кого какие есть идеи. Буду благодарен за любую наводку!

**P.S.:** сайт не является SPA

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, основной информацией, по которой сервер выявляет кандидатов на бан, является следующее:

1. Частота одинаковых запросов
2. IP
3. Данные о клиенте (браузере)

По первому пункту всё достаточно индивидуально.
По второму - купите несколько десятков прокси IP (например тут: https://proxy6.net/) и при создании объекта браузера используйте параметр proxy=...
По третьему пункту используйте модуль UserAgent - он попытается вас замаскировать.

Comment: понял, спасибо! Вопрос по 3 пункту: если я просто при запуске парсера подменю агент в инспекторе кода на Googlebot - это нормально сработает?

Comment: и здесь `при создании объекта браузера используйте параметр proxy=` я правильно понимаю, что есть команда в ubuntu, которая при каждой итерации скраппинга закидывать эти `ip` в параметр `proxy ` браузера ?

Comment: @Vsevolod -"есть команда в ubuntu". - Вы говорили о скрипте на Python. ОС и браузер в задачах скраппинга вторичны. Практически все программы для скраппинга основаны на использовании трёх основных модулей: 1) requests 2)  bs4 (BeautifulSoup) 3) selenium Это всё - очень большая тема и здесь её обсуждать нет смысла. Почитайте лучше хотя бы "Современный скрапинг веб-сайтов с помощью Python." Митчелл Р.

Comment: @Vsevolod - "подменю агент в инспекторе кода на Googlebot " - Я лично не пробовал, но повторю - специально для этого есть модуль *fake_useragent* - используйте его и не заморачивайтесь.